# FromAsync Method on a IAsyncResult instance: "does not contain definition for 'FromAsync'"

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, download, .net-framework-version

I need to use a class that allows me to use "Range" on the header and, at the same time, update a progressbar. 
I saw a post and someone posted the following code, that should help HttpWebRequest implement a progressbar:

```
public static void CopyToStreamAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, Action<Stream, Stream, Exception> completed, 
                                         Action<uint> progress, uint bufferSize, uint? maximumDownloadSize, TimeSpan? timeout)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        Action<Exception> done = exception =>
        {
            if (completed != null)
            {
                completed(source, destination, exception);
            }
        };

        int maxDownloadSize = maximumDownloadSize.HasValue ? (int)maximumDownloadSize.Value : int.MaxValue;
        int bytesDownloaded = 0;
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, new[] { maxDownloadSize, buffer.Length }.Min(), null, null);
        Action<IAsyncResult, bool> endRead = null;
        endRead = (innerAsyncResult, innerIsTimedOut) =>
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesRead = source.EndRead(innerAsyncResult);
                if (innerIsTimedOut) done(new TimeoutException());

                int bytesToWrite = new[] { maxDownloadSize - bytesDownloaded, buffer.Length, bytesRead }.Min();
                destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
                bytesDownloaded += bytesToWrite;

                if (progress != null && bytesToWrite > 0) progress((uint)bytesDownloaded);

                if (bytesToWrite == bytesRead && bytesToWrite > 0)
                {
                    asyncResult = source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, new[] { maxDownloadSize, buffer.Length }.Min(), null, null);
                    asyncResult.FromAsync((ia, isTimeout) => endRead(ia, isTimeout), timeout);

                }
                else
                {
                    done(null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                done(exc);
            }
        };

        asyncResult.FromAsync((ia, isTimeout) => endRead(ia, isTimeout), timeout);
    }
```

The problem is I can't even test it, 'cause the "asyncResult.FromAsync" returns a  "does not contain a definition for 'FromAsync' and no extension method 'FromAsync'" error.

Can someone Help me understand which references or which .NET Framework i should use so the code works?

Thanks

Comment: If you look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see there is no FromAsync method on that interface. Maybe it is a custom extension hiding the use of [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Maybe. In fact, i tried verifying it, but the use of timeout confused me.